# Doesn't build project on TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I wrote program, which work with office word. This program use .Net 4.0. It is successfully built on visual studio 2010. But when I start build definition , the build was failed with exception:

```
ThisAddIn.Designer.cs (16): The type or namespace name 'AddInBase' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Tools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
ThisAddIn.Designer.cs (228): The type or namespace name 'RibbonCollectionBase' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I don't know how it's fixed. I didn't install on TFS server Office 2010. I copied only directory, which reference to VS: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14

Can you advice me how it's fixed?

Comment: its clear that issue is an assembly reference in your project. may be you need "Microsoft Office 2010 includes Primary Interop Assemblies (PIAs)". see this link may be helpful http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install Office 2010 Components on your build Server.